# this cannot be nulll django..?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

my email should be ended with "ac.uk"

so i put this one in form

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  def clean_email(self):
    if not self.cleaned_data['email'].endswith('ac.uk'):
       raise forms.ValidationError('You need to use ac ID')
```

UserCreationForm

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}) )
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password confirmation'}))


class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    def __init__(self, auto_id='%s', *args, **kwargs):
        super(Meta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Mother_language'].choices = ('','Please choose ') + models.Language_list
        self.fields['Mother_language'].choices = ('','Please choose ') + models.Language_list
    widgets = {
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30,'placeholder': 'Email'}),
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30,'placeholder': 'UserName'}),
        'status_message': forms.TextInput(attrs={'height':50,'placeholder': 'Write your message'}),

    }

    fields = ('email','username','Mother_language','Nationality','Wish_language','Profile_image','status_message')
```

and my view.

```
def register(request):
  registered = False
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = MyUserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():       



        user = user_form.save()
        user.save()

        if 'Profile_image' in request.FILES:
                user.Profile_image = request.FILES['Profile_image']

                user.save()
                registered = True

    else:
       print(user_form.errors) 

else:
    user_form = MyUserCreationForm()

return render(request,
            'LanguageExchange/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form,
            'registered': registered})
```

when I remove MyUserCreationForm, it is working, but when i do, it is not...
and also, it said this field cannot be null....

plz help me.

Comment: What's the use of `__init__` inside the Meta class?

Comment: this is for widget..

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value from your clean method.

```
def clean_email(self):
  email = self.cleaned_data['email']
  if not email.endswith('ac.uk'):
     raise forms.ValidationError('You need to use ac ID')
  return email
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.